# Plastic SCM Branch Visual Bug

Tags: plasticscm

I was trying to delete an empty branch that accidentally got created, when to my surprise it said that this weird little branch had a child! Which was strange, because visually it did not appear to have a child, it didn't even have any change-sets in it. I looked into its children and somehow a branch that was split off from this empty branches parent somehow became the child of the empty branch! I was wondering if there was a way to move this child back to the parent of the empty where it belongs or should I just resign myself to having a weird outlier?

What branch explorer visually says I have:

```
----main branch---|ch1|---------|ch2|---------|ch5|
                   | \                         /
                   |  \
                   | |ch3|---real branch---|ch4|
                   |
                    \
                     \----empty branch---
```

what I actually have:

```
----main branch---|ch1|----------------------|ch2|--------------------|ch5|
                   \                                                   /
                    \                                                 /
                     \                                               /
                      \----empty branch---\                         /
                                           \                       /
                                          |ch3|---real branch---|ch4|
```

what I want:

```
----main branch---|ch1|---------|ch2|--------|ch5|
                    \                         /
                     \                       /
                    |ch3|---real branch---|ch4|
```

Comment: Not sure if merging to the empty branch and then renaming it would work as a workaround in your environment.